# dynamic query return zero value

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

i am trying to return some result from my table but my query return none result

here is how i execute my stored procedure

```
EXEC spLog '145',' ','2531'
```

and this is my stored procedure example, the concert is the same, return some value from my table

```
Created Procedure spLog
 @logID nvarchar(400),
 @logAction nvarchar(400),
 @userId nvarchar(400)
AS
Begin
DECLARE @query nvarchar(4000)

if(LEN(@logID)>0)
BEGIN
SET @query = @query + 'Select * From LogTable where logID in ('+@logID+') AND userID = '+@userId + ''
END
if (LEN(@logAction)>0)
BEGIN
SET @query = @query + 'Select * From logAction where logAction in ('+@logAction+') AND userID = '+@userId + ''
END

EXEC sp_executesql @query

END
```

the column naming and table naming is just an example, ignore it, my 2 table consist of item that i want but my return result was none, it should return me something instead of none =(

my expected result is [logTable result]+[LogAction result] or [logTable result] or [LogAction result]

Comment: Try to replace `logID in ('+@logID+')` with `logID = '+@logID+'`

Comment: @AndreyGordeev my parameter format will be something with comma =) eg '145,156'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the `@query` variable but have never set it's initial value - thus having it being `NULL` at the beginning.

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(4000)
```

Later you concatenate a string to your variable, and concatenating `NULL + 'something'` will still make it `NULL`

```
SET @query = @query + 'Select * From LogTable where logID in ('+@logID+') AND userID = '+@userId + ''
```

Just replace it with

```
 SET @query = 'Select * From LogTable where logID in ('+@logID+') AND userID = '+@userId + ''
```

or set your variable to blank string earlier up:

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(4000)
SET @query = ''
```

Comment: you are right, but i want to make use of 2 query, i cannot just run for one query

Comment: i just try, it doesnt work, when logid & logaction exist, my logaction result will replaced the logid result, my expected result is logid + logaction

Comment: Just use `SET @query = ''` at the beginning, and leave `SET @query = @query + ' SELECT...'` in your ifs

Comment: And make sure to add space between two queries - or even better - add semi-colon at the end of both queries + '; '